# VS Code: Search multiple directories

Tags: visual-studio-code

When searching, VS Code has the ability to list **files to include** to scope the search.  This is used by default when using the "find in folder" feature.  For example, searching `src` results in `./src` as the **files to include**.

Is there a syntax I can use to list multiple directories here?  For example, I want to search `./src` and `./lib` in one search.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Did you try a comma like `./dir1, ./dir2`? For me it seems to work

[image: Filter with comma]

Comment: Wow, I know I tried that (likely first).  I bet I fat-fingered something and then started looking for a more complex option (when the simple one really worked).  Thanks!.

Comment: Also works for absolute paths or network sharing outside of working folder, nice.

Answer (score 4):

By the way, here is the documentation of 'files to include': https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options

In particular, you can use glob notation. Also, VS Code will include/exclude certain directories or files by default, depending on your `settings.json`, in case anyone still sees unexpected behaviour.